# How Do I Restrict Access To Viewing Azure DevOps Project Settings?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to add a group/user to an Azure DevOps project with just access to repositories and pipelines.

If I deny "View project-level information" they don't have access to the project at all.

If I allow the "View project-level information" it gives them a read-only access to the Project Settings including permissions to see users and members of other groups etc.

It seems unbelievable that such a basic security and privacy hole exists.
Am I missing something in the config because I have never seen this in any other application and I find it hard to believe that everyone else using Azure DevOps finds this acceptable.
The easiest equivalent is GitHub (that Microsoft now owns) and you can't see the project settings if you are just a contributor.

How do I give external contractors access to the project to work but prevent them from viewing the Project Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to restrict access to the Team Project - Project Settings page. The only thing that comes close is the feature that is now in preview: [Limit user visibility and collaboration to specific projects](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/limit-user-visibility-and-collaboration-to-specific-projects/), which will enable you to restrict access to the Organization Settings. You could suggest this feature in the [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=21&entry=problem).

Comment: I marked it as accepted since this seems to be the case. I also suggested the feature as you suggested https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/restrict-access-to-viewing-azure-devops-project-se/1549025 I don't really understand how this is acceptable to anyone else using the system though.